# org mode - babel params variable is void

Tags: org-mode, variables

After upgrade org mode version to 9, the babel variable params is void.

Below example works fine in org 8 version:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output
(print params)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: ((:comments . "") (:shebang . "") (:cache . "no") (:padline . "") (:noweb . "no") (:tangle . "no") (:exports . "code") (:results . "replace output") (:session . "none") (:hlines . "yes") (:colnames . "no") (:result-type . output) (:result-params "output" "replace") (:rowname-names) (:colname-names))
```

But if we run the same code in org 9.0.5, I got below error message:

```
let: Symbol’s value as variable is void: params
```

Is it changed to another name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is now called `org-babel-default-header-args`. There are also similar variables for each language supported by babel. I don't remember what `params` meant in older versions, however, so I'm not sure if this is an exact replacement.

BTW, `C-h-v org-babel- TAB` is a nice way to find out all the variables whose names have the prefix `org-babel-`. And one thing that org 9.x has going for it is that it has much more predictable names for variables and functions in general.

EDIT: I read your comment and took a look through the code: I don't think that what you want can be done with unmodified org-mode. I was only able to do it by adding a (dynamically bound) variable and assigning to it the (internal) value of params just before the block was executed. Obviously, that invalidates your warranty :-). Here's the diff:

```
diff --git a/lisp/ob-core.el b/lisp/ob-core.el
index 9f67000..dfcc7a9 100644
--- a/lisp/ob-core.el
+++ b/lisp/ob-core.el
@@ -628,6 +628,8 @@ a list with the following pattern:
    (setf (nth 2 info) (org-babel-generate-file-param name (nth 2 info)))
    info))))

+(defvar org-babel-params)
+
 ;;;###autoload
 (defun org-babel-execute-src-block (&optional arg info params)
   "Execute the current source code block.
@@ -696,6 +698,7 @@ block."
         (capitalize lang)
         (let ((name (nth 4 info)))
           (if name (format " (%s)" name) "")))
+       (setq org-babel-params params)
    (if (member "none" result-params)
        (progn (funcall cmd body params)
           (message "result silenced"))
```

The source block would be modified to print `org-babel-params`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the default ones, but I wish to get the merged list with user defined list (e.g. :results output above). I see a function org-babel-merge-params in ob-core.el but not sure if I can call it.

Comment: You can call it but the problem is with what args? Both `info` and `params` are only known internally. I edited my answer to "externalize" the value of `params` (after it is set to its final value), but it requires changes to the code.

Comment: Cool, I have updated my ob-core at ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20170210, but it didn't take effect. Any special steps need to be done?

Comment: Just googled and run the compile command from emacs, now change works for my test example above. Really cool.But I still fail to run the example from http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-dot-diagrams.html. So that means call org-babel-execute:dot from elisp code doesn't work on org 9 now! Wish it can be fixed in later release.

Comment: That's because `org-babel-execute:dot`  returns nil , but the code block is run by `org-babel-execute:emacs-lisp` which turns it into the *string* "nil". `org-babel-execute:dot` expects the caller to interpret that as "I've already written the file, so you shouldn't bother" but `org-babel-execute-src-block` does not know that (it does not get nil back, it gets the string "nil") and proceeds to write the file with "nil" in it. You might want to post this on the org-mode mailing list and point back here for context.

Comment: BTW, try to run the dot example without the call to `org-babel-execute:dot`. The emacs lisp block will write the dot code into the file, but when you try to open that file, emacs (without the help of org-babel) apparently figures out that the file contains dot code but has a ".png" suffix, so it runs dot on it and shows you the PNG. Magic!

Comment: Thanks for your help to get the clear root cause. I have requested maillist memeber, pending approve now. Can you give more details about your workaround to open ".dot" as "png"? when I try it, it will open as a text file.

Comment: I don't completely understand the mechanism , but I suspect  you'll need an emacs built with the appropriate libraries (libpng in particular). Whether that's enough, I don't know. If I find time, I might try some more experiments and post my findings somewhere, but don't hold your breath!

Comment: You also need ImageMagick.

Comment: Oh, just download the git version and figured out the trouble is made by this commit "041ca4b6f ob-core: Do not return results on writing to file". after revert this commit, elisp call babel dot function works fine.

Comment: BTW, the magic that I described earlier is done by image-mode.

Answer (score 3):

Call function `org-babel-get-src-block-info` and access the 3rd element instead.

```
#+NAME: nodes
| From | To | Weight |
|------+----+--------|
| A    | B  |      3 |
| A    | C  |      2 |
| B    | D  |      4 |
| B    | E  |      5 |
| C    | F  |     10 |

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :imagename test.png :results output raw :var nodes=nodes
  (defun rowfun(x)
    (format "%s -> %s [label=%s];" (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x) (nth 2 x)))
  (defun dotgen(nodes)
    (let ((dotbegin "digraph {\nnode [shape=circle]\n")
          (dotend "\n}"))
      (concat dotbegin
              (mapconcat #'rowfun nodes "\n")
              dotend)))
  (let* ((params (nth 2 (org-babel-get-src-block-info)))
         (imagename (cdr (assq :imagename params))))
    (assq-delete-all :imagename params)
    (push `(:file . ,imagename) params)
    (org-babel-execute:dot (dotgen nodes) params) 
    (princ (format "[[./%s]]" imagename)))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[./test.png]]
```

Output:

[image]

Another more generic solution is using two src block, one for elisp to generate the dot description; the other one is the dot src block with the elisp src as input var.

```
#+NAME: nodes
| From | To | Weight |
|------+----+--------|
| A    | B  |     13 |
| A    | C  |      2 |
| B    | D  |      4 |
| B    | E  |      5 |
| C    | F  |     10 |

#+NAME: elisp-src
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var nodes=nodes
  (defun rowfun(x)
    (format "%s -> %s [label=%s];" (nth 0 x) (nth 1 x) (nth 2 x)))
  (defun dotgen(nodes)
    (let ((dotbegin "digraph {\nnode [shape=circle]\n")
          (dotend "\n}"))
      (concat dotbegin
              (mapconcat #'rowfun nodes "\n")
              dotend)))
  (dotgen nodes)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file dot.png :var dotdesc=elisp-src
$dotdesc
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:dot.png]]
```